# Custom Item Layout Bubbles chat like Messenger

Tags: android

I want to make chat bubbles like this [chat bubbles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNTSn.png).

I have an adapter to do everything like the picture, but I can't change the layout for the same . I want to make background of chat bubbles change when i add item like messenger app.

How can i make it?

[chat bubbles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNTSn.png)

Comment: You can create your own custom drawable in xml and use that custom drawable as the background of your 'TextView'. There are a lot of tutorials on the internet that explain how to create the necessary drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 3 xml drawable:

- one for first message with **left-bottom, left-top and right-top** border radius
- second for inner messages with **left-bottom and left-top** border radius
- third for last message with **left-bottom, left-top and right-bottom** border radius

now in your adapter you can decide which drawable to use depending on the previus and next message of your adapters message list

For example if previus messages of current message in adapter is not from current user(the user who logged in to app), so you should choose the first drawable. And if the previus messages in adapter is from current user, so you should choose second second drawable. And if the previus message is from current user and the next message is not, so you should use third drawable

Comment: nice answer , i'll try it